# Matching abc/? in routes file

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

How do you match abc/? in play 2 ? Docs for play 1 show this will work, but I can't find resources for play 2.

Comment: Do you mean trailing slash ? In Play framework it's important too (what's more - it's most important for search engines as link with or without slash aren't the same) please, specify what are you asking for, I think that I'll find a solution...

Answer (score 0):

In routes file, just use this:

```
GET   /abc          controllers.Clients.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fix:

In `conf/routes` add this line before resources and after more specific rest calls.

```
# Detrail url
GET     /*path/                     controllers.BlogController.redirectUntrailed(path: String)
```

Then in controller, add this Action.

```
def redirectUntrailed(path: String) = Action {
  MovedPermanently("/" + path)
}
```